# Нужно сравнить изображения

Tags: c++, c, сравнение

Нужно сравнить два изображения (.jpg), чуть позже, возможно, ещё и видео. 
написал функцию:

```
void unique(List<Photo> &list)
{

string subject_name, object_name;
size_t i = 0;

while (list.Get_Size())
{
    subject_name = list[i].Get_data(LOCATION) + list[i].Get_data(NAME);

    ifstream subject(subject_name, ios::binary | ios::ate);
    size_t subject_size = subject.tellg();
    subject.seekg(0, ios::beg);
    char *subject_buf = new char[subject_size];
    subject.read(subject_buf, subject_size);
    subject.close();

    for (size_t j = i + 1; j < list.Get_Size(); j++)
    {
        object_name = list[j].Get_data(LOCATION) + list[j].Get_data(NAME);

        ifstream object(subject_name, ios::binary | ios::ate);
        size_t object_size = object.tellg();
        if (subject_size != object_size)
        {
            object.close();
            break;
        }
        object.seekg(0, ios::beg);
        char *object_buf = new char[object_size];
        object.read(object_buf, object_size);
        object.close();

        for (size_t k = 0; k < subject_size; k++)
        {
            if (subject_buf[k] != object_buf[k])
                break;

            if (k == subject_size)
            {
                list.removeAt(j);
                delete[] object_buf;
                delete[] subject_buf;

                unique(list);
                return;
            }
        }

        delete[] object_buf;
    }

    i++;
    delete[] subject_buf;

    if (i > list.Get_Size() - 1)
        return;
}
}
```

Сравниваю файлы побитого, если ничего не напутал. Файлы открываю в бинарном режиме и в режиме чтения.
Первым делом проверяю, не равны ли размеры. Затем, поочерёдно сравниваю в цикле `for` каждый символ: если встречаются разные, выхожу из текущего цикла и сравниваю следующий  файл, если все были одинаковые и дошли до последнего - делаю вывод, что это копия фотографии и, следовательно, удаляю.

как только происходит удаление, рекурсивно вхожу в эту же функцию.

Сам я ошибки в алгоритме не вижу, может, знатоки подскажут?

P.S. Не уверен, что нужны рекурсия и такое сравнение посимвольное, но добавил их в отчаянных попытках заставить `э_т_о` работать.

P.P.S. Есть предположение, что при таком подходе, учитывается имя файла, а они, конечно, разные. Если так, подскажите как просто сравнить фотографии.

P.P.P.S. Про сравнения фоток на форуме читал, но мне не надо выделять объекты, сравнивать цвет штор, количество кресел и наличие инопланетян. Я просто хочу узнать являются ли два файла копией. Будь там даже один иной пиксель - для меня они уже разные.

Заранее спасибо)

Comment: Если вам нужно искать точные копии файлов и удалять дубликаты, то можно не городить огород и просто считать и сравнивать md5sum, например.

Comment: @iksuy , прошу прощения, не нашёл встроенного решения по считыванию этого md5. Оно есть в стандартных библиотеках или придётся скачивать MD5.h с гитхаба?.. если это докачивать что-то надо - спорный вопрос, что из этого _городить огород_

Comment: @МихаилКраев, md5 - это специализированный алгоритм расчета хэша файла (т.е. некоторого набора циферок, однозначно идентифицирующих файл). Суть такова: вместо побайтового сравнения двух файлов, вы сравниваете эти циферки, что существенно ускоряет задачу (но посчитать хэши все же придется)

Comment: Сравнивать побайтово все равно придется, так как сравнение только по хэшу может давать ложные положительные результаты. А для сравнения побайтово есть быстрая функция `memcmp`.

Comment: Чтобы посчитать хеши все равно придется вычитывать все файлы. Если задача стоит сравнить два файла, в расчете хешей нет смысла, но если нужно проколбасить дерево с 100500 файлами на предмет дупликатов по три и более штук, то хеши существенно ускоряют процесс. Причина в том, что ваши файлы могут различаться где--то в конце и чтобы это определить, нужно просмотреть весь файл. И так несколько раз. В случае хеша, нужно просмотреть очень мало, а несовпадение обнаружится практически сразу.

Comment: Сравнить 2 файла -- [man cmp](https://linux.die.net/man/1/cmp)

Comment: На счёт md5, хорошо, я пока изучаю эту тему, всем спасибо за информацию. Но, всё таки, сейчас алгоритм сравнивает побайтого, и он не работает. А спрашивал я именно про него.

Comment: @VTT, за функцию спасибо, буду знать. попробовал её в своей программе, однако результат был тот же, файлы одинаковые точно есть, но функция распознала их как разные. Да и стоит ли такую простую вещь на стороннюю функцию переводить? Спорный вопрос.

Comment: @avp, прошу прощения, не разобрался по ссылке, что там?

Comment: @BwanaTheMaster, я учту ваш совет, спасибо) сделаю проверку на количество файлов и, исходя из этого, буду выбирать алгоритм)

Comment: @МихаилКраев, описание утилиты, которая сравнивает файлы. Ее можно использовать в скрипте (если у вас работа, которую просто надо сделать). Если же обязательно хотите в *своей программе*, то  если надо сравнить только 2 файла, однозначно, считать хэши (md5, sha или даже просто crc) медленнее, чем просто сравнивать. Сравнивать лучше поблочно, используя для сравнения `memcmp()`. А вот если надо найти дубликаты во множестве файлов, то группруйте по размеру, считайте хэш (в группах), отсортируйте хэши и (если не верите, что хэш однозначен) сравнивайте только соседей в группе с одинаковым хэшем.

Comment: Так, я уточняю, есть программа, код выше, хочу чтоб работало, но не работает, вопрос - почему? что не так в побайтовом сравнении файлов? 
я обязательно научусь сравнивать хэш, но сейчас меня очень интересует, почему побайтово сравнить две фотки нельзя, ведь это всего на всего файлы.